# Rename files based on filenames in a csv

Tags: python, file, csv, rename

I have a csv file 'names.csv' containing two columns 'old_name' and 'new_name' such that each row has new names corresponding to the old file names.
I want to replace all the old filenames of the files in '/home/docs/abc' directory with the new names. (The names file is in the same directory and no need to change its name). I am tyring with the csv module and array method but unable to get the results.File extension will remain same '.csv'

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by built in libraries `os` and `csv`

Python code:

```
import os
import csv

with open('names.csv') as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f)
    for line in lines:
        os.rename(line[0], line[1])
```

Example of names.csv:

```
old_name.txt, new_name.txt
old_name.jpg, new_name.jpg
```

In this case your python code must be in the same directory with csv file

Comment: Thanks for the anwer however it is showing the following error:                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renamefile.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.rename(line[0], line[1])
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: My old filenames are the default filenames from a batch online download as SearchResults(1).csv, SearchResults(2).csv, SearchResults(3).csv........

Comment: are they in the same directory as where the script is executed from? If not, you will have to add that portion of the path to the filenames

Comment: If your csv file not in the same directory with your script? you have to specify path to your csv file `with open('path/to/names.csv') as f:`